# Python edited calendar output

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, calendar

I am trying to form a calendar which, given the month and year, will display that months days like this:

e.g

```
January 2018
S/tM/tT/tW/tT/tF/tS
t01/t02/t03...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider python's [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.TextCalendar(calendar.SUNDAY).prmonth(2018, 1)
    January 2018
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 0):

(I wish I have enough reputation to make comments rather than put an answer... because this is really not an answer to how to write a calendar app using python.)

if you are using ipython notebook, you can execute shell command:
`!cal 1 2018`, which will display like:

`January 2013

Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa

       1  2  3  4  5

 6  7  8  9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16 17 18 19

20 21 22 23 24 25 26

27 28 29 30 31`

Comment: I know, it is part of my assignment. I had so many algorithmical problems which were fun to solve, but i have no idea how to do this

Comment: @davedwards just posted a code using python's calendar module. I think it is great!